# Connecting to MongoDB running on Amazon EC2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

So I have two EC2 instances launched in the same region and subnet on EC2. I have setup the security permissions for the instances like so:

Instance A: Receives traffic from ELB and can Outbound anywhere
Instance B: Can received traffic from Instance A's security group on port 27017 (Mongo).

Both instances have Private and Public IPs from the same subnets.

SSH permission to both instances is granted for my IP as well.

So here is the issue, I confirmed that Instance B has Mongo listening on port 27017

[image]

I also confirmed that both instances are in the same VPC. Yet Instance A cannot reach Instance B via port 27017 below is the security group settings for Instance B

[image]

The security group listed to the right is the group attached to Instance A.

I ran reachability analyzer and it succeeded

[image]

Yet despite all this Instance A cannot reach Instance B. I have run nMap, and tried to connect to Mongo in various ways all result in connection refused, or timeouts. I am frankly stumped so any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say A can't reach B you mean you can't connect to Mongo or even a simple TCP host:port check fails? Also, could you share your mongo config file?

Comment: turned out to be a Mongo Config issue, it for some reason did not auto bind to the internal ip address only localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone with a similar issue going forward the issue was when Mongo installs on Ec2 through apt it doesn't by default enable the internal or external ip access to Mongo via port 27017.

To solve this you need to edit your mongod.conf file using the steps shown here

[How To Configure Remote Access for MongoDB on Ubuntu 20.04 | DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-remote-access-for-mongodb-on-ubuntu-20-04)